# Let $\text{trace}(AM)\ge0$ where $M$ is psd, is $\text{trace}(A)\ge0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, positive-semidefinite

Let $\text{trace}(AM)\ge0$ where $M$ is positive semidefinite, so we know that $\text{trace}(M)\ge0$ since the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Is $\text{trace}(A)\ge0$?

Comment: Hey Kay.. what do you think about my answer?

Comment: Great. I actually voted it first as it cleared my doubt. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm glad you have found the answer useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sufficient to consider diagonal matrices to see that $\text{trace}(A)$ can be anything.

Take for example $M=\text{diag}(1000,1,1)$  and $A=\text{diag}(1,-2,-3)$.